# Multi-tenant authentication flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, oauth-2.0, nestjs

How do companies handle authentication in their multi-tenant web apps?

Essentially I have a single `PostgreSQL` database instance with many tables. Each table has a workspace_id column which I will use to use to grant/deny access. You can think of a workspace as a client and a single user can be associated with multiple workspaces.

My initial thought was to:

1. Use the frontend app and let the user send the email and password to
   the backend.
2. Backend validates details and returns all the workspaces the user belongs to.
3. The frontend app displays the workspaces.
4. User selects the workspace they want to login into. The id of the workspace and the user details that were passed in step 1 is again to the backend.
5. The backend validates again all the details and issues a `jwt` token containing the user details and the workspace id.
6. Later when the user tries to access any resource I will extract the workspace id from the token to check if the user has access to a resource or not.

I am halfway through implementing what I've described above but I am not sure if that's the best approach. What do you think?

Comment: Why not just embed all the workspaces in the token? Or not use JWT and check available workspaces on a given API call

Comment: Multitenancy is a quite complex topic and it's better to ask for advice on another network's site

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I would call this multi-tenancy - really it is just a case of different users with different `claims`:

- Users should log in once, then have access to the data that their user identity is entitled to

When your UI calls APIs, the back end should receive a JWT access token with either of these payloads. The second of these is preferred, but not all systems support that:

- The user ID only
- The user ID plus an array of workspace IDs

**SIMPLEST OPTION**

This might just be to look up the user's workspace IDs whenever an API request is received, based on the user ID in the JWT access token, as in Joe's comment above.

**CLAIMS PRINCIPAL**

If workspace IDs are used frequently for authorization across many API requests, then a better option is to design a `Claims Principal` object, containing data commonly used by the API for authorization, and containing the important IDs. It might look like this for a particular user:

```json
{
  sub: "wdvohjkerwt8",
  userID: 234,
  workspaceIDs: [2, 7, 19]
}
```

This object typically needs to be comprised of both Identity Data (stored by the Authorization Server) and also domain specific data. The above userID might be a database key, whereas the subject claim is often a generated value.

When an API request is received, you can either read all claims from the JWT access token, or combine domain specific data with the JWT data.

The Claims Principal is then injected where needed, so that your API authorization logic can be coded in a simple way. In your case this will involve filtering workspaces when working with collections, or denying access if the user specifically tries to access a workspace they are not entitled to.

Here is some sample Node.js code of mine that does this, using a `region array claim`:

- [Claims Principal Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts#L30)
- [Authorizing Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/logic/services/companyService.ts)
- [Doc](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/13/updated-api-coding-key-points/)

Comment: have you got an article/existing nodejs project I can have a look at?

Comment: Yes - I added some links to resources of mine and updated my answer